# Setting language while creating Docusign envelope

Tags: docusignapi

We are passing some Japanese characters in the email subject field in the input JSON while invoking the Envelopes:create rest API call to create the envelope. On the response JSON from Docusign we see the email subject is garbled up, has different/junk characters. This is how it reflects in the email received as well. How do we ensure the characters are not lost, is that a account level setting for the language or something that needs to be processed and sent in the input payload JSON.

Comment: can you post some of these characters here? I'd like to try this out please

Comment: somehow it doesn't allow me to post the characters here, you can use google translate English to japaneese and pick the japaneese conversion of any, I had used "Please sign this document"

Comment: この文書に署名してください
Is the above correct?

Comment: I wonder if you are not using the same encoding as the more common Unicode for these characters. If you can't copy/paste here - it won't work with DocuSign either.

Comment: Hi Inbar,Yes the text you typed is what I see この文書に署名してください, surprisingly I am able to paste now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is probably related to the encoding, or the type of Unicode you use for these Japanese characters.
See old post on this topic - [Docusign Rest with UTF-8 Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764977/docusign-rest-with-utf-8-characters).
I should say that if you can't copy/paste these characters here, I wonder if they are encoded with UTF (Unicode) at all.
UTF-8 and UTF-16 are supported by DocuSign.

Comment: From the post mentioned above I currently have not set the encoding type setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

Comment: were you able to do that and did it help?

Comment: Trying both these changes, will update you on the results.Thanks so much

Comment: So I am mistaken we already had the encoding set,i added the code to complete encode the envelope before sending and it resolved the issue.Thanks so much for the feedback.I will mark this answered.