# Using non-Latin UTF-8 characters in HTML passed to Docusign API

Tags: java, unicode, docusignapi

I am passing an HTML document as part of an envelope creation request to the Docusign REST API. When I include multibyte UTF-8 data, it comes out in the resulting Docusign envelope document interpreted as individual characters. For example, when I include the Russian word "банан", the first letter has UTF-8 encoding U+D0B1 but it comes out as Ð (U+00D0) and ± (U+00B1).

I was concerned it could be an issue on my side so I enabled Docusign server-side API request logging. I can see in the log of the request that the string is properly logged as "банан" on the way in. This HTML is included as part of a multipart request, and the header for this part includes:

```
--Boundary_4_1344004434_1669225218640
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="foo.html"; name="foo.html"; documentid="1"
```

the header for the entire multipart request includes:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary_4_1344004434_1669225218640
Content-Length: 95556
```

How can I get the resulting document to properly make use of UTF-8 characters? Am I doing something wrong or is it a limitation of Docusign's HTML -> PDF conversion support?

Note: including UTF-8 encoded values for text tabs in the same request works perfectly fine. The only issue is characters within the HTML that gets converted by Docusign into PDF.

ETA: the information from [Docusign Rest with UTF-8 Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764977/docusign-rest-with-utf-8-characters) was not helpful. the first response is to use HTML encoding, but I have no way to cleanly apply that to my whole HTML input as I want the < and > characters in tags to stay intact, and the other "solution" the author appears to have went with is just to encode using ISO-8859-1 rather than UTF-8.

Comment: weird, this totally wasn't working and then all of a sudden it did start working. am I hallucinating or did Docusign maybe fix something server-side? or I started hitting a differently configured server? lol

Answer (score 0):

started working, I guess it was a code problem on my end